# Calculate Scala average

Tags: scala, average

I need to calculate the average of three ages in Scala. I have tried the method shown below, but it did not work. Please help.

```
sealed abstract class Component
case class Life (age:Int) extends Component

object Life extends Component{
  def main(args: Array[String]){
    val lives = List{Life(10), Life(20), Life(30)}
    def livesMean (l:List[Life]):Double = {
        println(livesMean)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In your question you should provide your code in order to be referenced in the future for anyone who may have the same problem with you. A link to an image may not always be available.

Comment: "it did not work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have declared list of object of lives incorrectly. And to find average, take the sum of ages and divide it by size of list.

```
sealed abstract class Component
case class Life (age:Int) extends Component

object Main extends Component{
    def main(args: Array[String]){
    val lives = List(Life(10), Life(20), Life(30))
    def livesMean (l:List[Life]):Double = lives.map(_.age).sum/lives.size
    println("average of lives "+ livesMean(lives))
  }
}
```

It is running. You can see it [here](https://ideone.com/dV0ZNT)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you're using to create `lives` isn't valid.  This should work:

```
abstract class Component

case class Life(age: Int) extends Component

object Life extends Component {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val lives = List(new Life(10), new Life(20), new Life(30))
        val livesMean: Double = lives.map(_.age).sum / lives.size
        println(livesMean) // 20.0
    }
}
```

Scala fiddle: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/Lyu9VRf/0

Comment: It doesn't print the "liveMean"

Comment: @test123test: "it doesn't work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with the code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?